# Event listener "message", based on event name making an API call with promise in angularJs, javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, message, addeventlistener

I am trying to listen to a "message", by adding an event listener and based on an `eventName` property in the event data which is coming as string, I need to make a promise and fetch some data from an API.
But this promise call is not happening.

Sample data:

```js
event.data = `{"eventName":"modal:open","eventData":{"state":"redeem","stateParams":{"rewardTitle":"Lab Coat Live - 35% Discount","rewardId":550288},"width":700,"src":"https://qa-crowdtwist.thermofisher.com/widgets/t/redeem/550288/#2"},"direction":"up","widgetId":13324,"version":2}`
```

If `"eventName": "reward:redeemed"` then I need to make the API call. But the promise is not executing neither throwing any error. Am I doing something wrong or is there any other procedure to make this promise to work?

```
const event = new Event("message");
$window.addEventListener(event.type, function (event) {
    if(typeof event.data === "string"){
        var data = event.data;
        var redeemed = false;
        if(data.indexOf("reward:redeemed")){
            redeemed = true;
        }
    }                
    if(redeemed){
        dataService.getUserPoints();                    
    }
}, false);
$window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: The easiest way to figure out what's going is to add `console.log()` and inspect the data. In Chrome devtools you can also set breakpoints and inspect the call stack and local variables. For example, add a console.log(event) above your first if statement. Inspect the output. Is `event.data` actually a string? Repeat until you find the issue. You should attempt to debug first before turning to stackoverflow.

Comment: In the code you show, `event` is a bare `Event` object with only its `type` set to `"message"`. It is not a `MessageEvent` and it doesn't have a `data` property. Also, even if it's not related to your current issue, `if( string.indexOf(sub_string) )` is not how you should check if a string contains a sub-string, this will only tell you whether the sub-string was found at the beginning of the string (index=0) in which case is won't enter the if block. If the sub-string isn't part of the string indexOf will return `-1` which is truthy. What you want is `if( string.includes( sub_string ) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the AngularJS framework modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Consider using the AngularJS event propagation mechanism. Scopes can propagate events in similar fashion to DOM events. The event can be [broadcasted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) to the scope children or [emitted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) to scope parents.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Events Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)